# How can I disable customer emails when order create using rest api in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api

Is there an API call or cart/quote setting I can use to turn off customer notifications just for the order confirmation?

I create order using this api 
Method:PUT 
url:
http://localhost/testproject/rest/V1/carts/{cart_id or quote_id}/order

Answer (score 0):

Disable the order confirmation email from the Magento Admin and send an email programmatically for website only:

```
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email > Order > Enabled = No
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_sendmail" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\SendMailOnOrderSuccess" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Observer/SendMailOnOrderSuccess.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SendMailOnOrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
     */
    protected $orderModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
     */
    protected $orderSender;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderModel
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderModel,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if (count($orderIds)) {
            $this->checkoutSession->setForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess(true);
            $order = $this->orderModel->create()->load($orderIds[0]);
            $this->orderSender->send($order, true);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity">
        <plugin name="enable_method" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentityPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Sales/Order/Order/Email/Container/OrderIdentityPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Container;

class OrderIdentityPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @return bool
     */
    public function aroundIsEnabled(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $returnValue = $proceed();

        $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess = $this->checkoutSession->getForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
        if (isset($forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess) && $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess) {
            if ($returnValue) {
                $returnValue = false;
            } else {
                $returnValue = true;
            }
            $this->checkoutSession->unsForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
        }

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to disable order confirmation from  api side not website side.

Comment: Please implement above code once and place order using API.

Comment: after follow this steps not sending emails of website orders.Please suggest how to send emails in website.

Comment: Try above updated code.

Comment: I try updated code but not getting any email. I recieved other emails like customer registration but not getting order confirmation email in website.Please check

Comment: Check once with default magento setup OR make sure execute function is working on the checkout success action.